# Magento 2 : mailchimp integration error

Tags: magento2, error, mailchimp, newsletter-subscriber

I am using magento version 2.3.2

I have installed extension : **Ebizmart mailchimp** extension

and I have api key for that, when i put api key in text box and that giving me alert box 
also giving same error on **"create mailchimp store"**

see sreenshot

[image]

anyone help in me, thanks in advance.

Comment: It means mailchimp store is not existing. You have to create from Magento also.

Comment: when i create it from magento then also get same error

Comment: Go to Magento 2 Admin Panel->MailChimp > Configuration->In Default Config drop-down, select a Magento 2 store you want to connect to new created MailChimp store->Read confirm message then click OK->In API Key (store view) drop-down, select the API key added for your MailChimp store->Tap Save Config

Comment: @VrajeshPatel ok let me try

Comment: @VrajeshPatel I have tried with this but no any luck, giving same error alert

Comment: Here is full guide. Please follow : http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/configuration-guide-m4m2

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue in the extension.
Akamai is the firewall that mailchimp uses, so is Akamai who is blocking your requests
Take a look at https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/article/Why-is-Akamai-blocking-me?language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for reply, Let me check :)